# What is mean by serializing from one VM to another when using JPA

Tags: serialization, jpa-2.0

I am reading JPA 2.0. I encounter a sentence that

```
We have used the transient modifier instead of the @Transient annotation so that 
if the Employee gets serialized from one VM to another then the translated name 
will get reinitialized to correspond to the locale of the new VM.

@Entity
public class Employee {
    @Id private int id;
    private String name;
    private long salary;
    transient private String translatedName;
    // ...
    public String toString() {
        if (translatedName == null) {
            translatedName = ResourceBundle.getBundle("EmpResources").getString("Employee");
        }
        return translatedName + ": " + id + " " + name;
    }
}
```

What I understood is that when we use @Entity annotation and container encounter it then it call JPA provider that do the things. Like map id to ID column in database. Although we didn't mention the @Column annotation on the name and salary, but by default it maps to column NAME and SALARY in database. We used transient on translatedName so the JAP leave it as it is, not mapping applied to it. It's just a field in this class. But i am unable to get the understanding of the sentence

```
if the Employee gets serialized from one VM to another
```

Someone please explain it to me? Also tell me that what i defined above about the workflow of JAP is correct? Like what happening when container encounter @Entity annotation?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a class implements the `java.io.Serializable` interface, instances of this class are serializable. That means that the JVM can transform the object into a sequence of bytes. These bytes can be sent over the network, or saved on a disk, and can be read by another VM and transformed back into a Java object.

If a field has the `transient` Java keyword, it means that this field will be ignored by this serialization mechanism. The field won't be serialized.

A field annotated with `@Transient` is considered as a non-persistent field by JPA. It won't save it in the database, and it won't load it from the database. But it will be serialized if the object is sent to another JVM.

The Java `transient` keyword automatically makes a field `@Transient`. This means that a `transient` field, won't be serialized, and won't be saved by JPA either.

Comment: Hhhhmm thanks. You mean if i use `@Transient` annotaion then data of this field won't save in database but it will be Serialize if my Employee calss implements Serializable interface. But with transient keyword, neither save to database nor become serializabe even if my Employee class implements Serializable? Am i right?

Comment: Thanks :) One thing more when we say persist the entity, it means save the record in the database. If the record do not save in the database, then we can't say that it become persist?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking here.

Comment: :) i am just asking what is mean, when you say `persist the instance of entity`, ok leave it, as i just started learning JPA, may be it will become clear to me after some time:). Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

In the "JEE5 world" you can use detached entities as you would have used transfer objects. (I am not judging whether this is a good idea or not!)

Thus you can call for example a service method (e.g. EJB 3 SLSB method) that returns an instance of Employee remotely with the usual remote-call semantics regarding serialization.

It should be noted, that if an instance of Employee was serialized successfully, then your Java Runtime might be broken, as the class does not implement Serializable.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to save the state of your entity arrtibute to DB and also don't want the state to get transferred to another jvm, then use `Transient` keyword.

If you don't want to save the state of your entity arrtibute to DB, but want the state to be transferred to another jvm, then use `@Transient` annotation.